# Filter collection of images with selected geometry

Tags: image, st-geometry, spatial-filter

I am developing an application to analyze the images of the districts of a region.
I select the districts this way and it works fine (see image)

```js
var selectd = ui.Select ({
   items: Object.keys (Districts),
   placeholder: 'Select District',
   onChange: function (i) {0
Map.addLayer (table.filter (ee.Filter.inList ('BARLO_DESC', [i])))
Map.centerObject (table.filter (ee.Filter.inList ('BARLO_DESC', [i])), 11)
```

But I can't get the selected district to be the geometry to filter the image collection, for example:

```
.filterBounds(selectd)
```

Code:

```js
/*====================================================
OBJECT DICTIONARY (WIDGETS)
======================================================*/


var bandas = {
'B1': [],
'B2': [],
'B3': [],
'B4': [],
'B5': [],
'B6': [],
'B7': [],
'B8': [],
'B8A': [],
'B9': [],
'B11': [],
'B12': [],
'AOT': [],
'WVP': [],
'SCL': [],
'TCI_R': [],
'TCI_G': [],
'TCI_B': [],
'MSK_CLDPRB': [],
'MSK_SNWPRB': [],
'QA10': [],
'QA20': [],
'QA60': [],

}


/* DISTRICT DICTIONARY */

var Distritos = {
'CRUCE DON SILVIO': [52],
'ZONA PELICANO':    [53],
'ZONA CAMPO KAREN': [54],
'ZONA PRATTS GRILL':    [55],
'ZONA MBUTURETA':   [66],
'ZONA JOEL ESTIGARRIBIA':   [71],
'ZONA MAYOR INFANTE RIVAROLA':  [72],
'ZONA EL SOLITARIO':    [83],
'ZONA GENERAL GARAY':   [222],
'ZONA PEDRO P PEÑA':    [223],
'ZONA POZO HONDO':  [224],
'MISTOLAR': [225],
'ZONA HEERNANDARIAS':   [226],
'ZONA LA PATRIA':   [227],
'ZONA AGROPIL': [228],

}

/***********************************************
 * STARTING THE APP
 * *********************************************/


var selectd = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(Distritos), 
  placeholder: 'Seleccione Disrito', 
  onChange: function(i){0
Map.addLayer(table.filter(ee.Filter.inList('BARLO_DESC', [i])))
Map.centerObject(table.filter(ee.Filter.inList('BARLO_DESC', [i])), 10)

  }
})

// print(selectd)
// var filtro = table.filter(ee.Filter.inList('BARLO_DESC'))

// /***********************************************
// PANEL CONTROL
// ************************************************/
// // var c = {};
   
// // c.controlPanel = ui.Panel();
// // c.map = ui.Map();
 
// // c.info = {};
// // c.info.titleLabel = ui.Label('Sistemas de Riego en el Acuifero Yrendá');
// // c.info.aboutlabel = ui.Label(
// //   'Análisis de la dinámica de la Vegetación y, especialmente de las pasturas'  +
// //   ' bajo riego con pivots, en el área del acuífero Yrendá, en el extremo' +
// //   ' Occidental del Chaco Paraguayo.');
  
// // c.info.panel = ui.Panel([
// //   c.info.titleLabel, c.info.aboutlabel
// //   ]);
// //     ui.root.clear();
// //     ui.root.add(c.controlPanel);
// //     ui.root.add(c.map);
    
// //     c.controlPanel.add(c.info.panel);
    
// //     c.controlPanel.style().set({
// //   width: '275px'
// // });

// /************************************************
// * OBJECT DICTIONARY (WIDGETS)
// **********************************************/
 
var dicobjetos = {
  Sliderfecha: ui.DateSlider({start: '2015-01-01', end:ee.Date(Date.now()), period: 15, onChange:function(){},style: {width:'240px'}}),
  select:{
    b1: ui.Select({items: Object.keys(bandas), placeholder: 'Sel.Band', onChange:function(){},style: {width:'70px'}}),
    b2: ui.Select({items: Object.keys(bandas), placeholder: 'Sel.Band', onChange:function(){},style: {width:'70px'}}),
    b3: ui.Select({items: Object.keys(bandas), placeholder: 'Sel.Band', onChange:function(){},style: {width:'70px'}}),
  },
  label: ui.Label('Min:', {}),
  slider:ui.Slider({min: 500, max: 5000, step: 100, onChange:function(){},style: {width:'240px'}}),
  label1: ui.Label('Max:', {}),
  slider1:ui.Slider({min: 500, max: 5000, step: 100, onChange:function(){},style: {width:'240px'}}),
  label2: ui.Label('Gamma:', {}),
  slider2:ui.Slider({min: 0, max: 3, step: 0.1, onChange:function(){},style: {width:'120px'}}),
  
}
  
  var panelv = ui.Panel({widgets: [
  dicobjetos.select.b1,
  dicobjetos.select.b2, 
  dicobjetos.select.b3], layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'), style: {backgroundColor:'00000000'}})
  
  
  var boton = ui.Button({label:'Aplicar', onClick:function(b){
    var coleccion = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2").filterBounds(table)
    .filterDate(ee.Date(dicobjetos.Sliderfecha.getValue()[0]).format('YYYY-MM-dd'),ee.Date(dicobjetos.Sliderfecha.getValue()[1]).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than', 10).mosaic()
    var layer = ui.Map.Layer(coleccion, {bands:[dicobjetos.select.b1.getValue(),dicobjetos.select.b2.getValue(),dicobjetos.select.b3.getValue()],
  min:dicobjetos.slider.getValue(), max: dicobjetos.slider1.getValue(),gamma:dicobjetos.slider2.getValue()}, 'Sentinel 2')
  Map.layers().set(0,layer)

  }})
  
  // MAIN PANEL
  var panel = ui.Panel({widgets: [
  dicobjetos.Sliderfecha, panelv,dicobjetos.label,
  dicobjetos.slider, dicobjetos.label1,dicobjetos.slider1,
  dicobjetos.label2,dicobjetos.slider2, selectd, boton ],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'), style: {backgroundColor:'00005555',position: 'top-left'}});
  Map.add(panel)
```